# python win32com Attribute Error in constants

Tags: python, com, ms-office, powerpoint, win32com

I tried to program with the `win32com` Python library to handle PowerPoint files. However when I pass constants to the function in the following way,

```
new_pre.ExportAsFixedFormat(options.output,
                            win32com.client.constants.ppFixedFormatTypePDF,
                            win32com.client.constants.ppFixedFormatIntentPrint,
                            win32com.client.constants.msoFalse,
                            win32com.client.constants.ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst,
                            win32com.client.constants.ppPrintOutputSixSlideHandouts,
                            win32com.client.constants.msoFalse,
                            win32com.client.constants.ppPrintAll,
                            False,
                            False,
                            False,
                            False,
                            PrintRange=None
                            )
```

it raises an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SharedDocuments/DokyPpf/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    win32com.client.constants.msoFalse,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 178, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(a)
AttributeError: msoFalse
```

Note that there is a [similar question](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/482449-win32com-client-constants-attributeerror) and the solution there is to use

```
EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
```

instead of

```
Dispatch("")
```

But, I already used `EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application")` and it's still not working...

[Here is the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746080(v=office.14).aspx#See%20Also) to the API reference of the corresponding VBA.

Comment: `happs = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")`  You cannot access services as you specify,

Comment: @dsgdfg I use ``app=win32com.client.EnsureDispatch("PowerPoint.Application")``,Is there something wrong?

Comment: Don't start flying before you learn to walk! Try the normal(GUI) and see the errors, then use the proxy.

Comment: try www.pptxbuilder.com?

Answer (score 1):

When you are running `EnsureDispatch`, `win32com` will automatically generate Python code corresponding to the type library of interest.

Depending a bit on your environment, the Python modules will be located somewhere around `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6`, with the modules being grouped by the CLSID of the type library you have generated code for.

For PowerPoint 2016, you would find a folder named `91493440-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B` whose `__init__.py` contains all the generated constants, including e.g. `ppFixedFormatTypePDF`.

Now, notably, the `MsoTriState` enum containing `msoFalse` is *not* part of the PowerPoint type library, which is why you are seeing your `AttributeError`s.

From a [quick look at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.msotristate.aspx), we find that the enum is part of the core Office libraries, contained in `mso.dll`. Depending once again on your setup, which version of Office you're using, and which architecture it targets, you should be able to dig up its ID by searching `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in your registry editor:

[image: regedit]

Here, we note that the type library has a CLSID of `{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}` and that the version number is 2.8. Knowing this, perhaps the easiest way to generate the code for the library, and thus the missing constant, is through `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule('{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}', 0, 2, 8)`:

```
In [16]: win32com.client.constants.msoFalse
AttributeError: msoFalse

In [17]: win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule('{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}', 0, 2, 8)
Out[17]: <module 'win32com.gen_py.2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52x0x2x8' from 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\
\Temp\\gen_py\\3.6\\2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52x0x2x8.py'>

In [18]: win32com.client.constants.msoFalse
Out[18]: 0
```

Now, knowing that `msoFalse` translates to a 0, you could, of course, also just skip the entire process and replace all occurrences of the constant with a 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 __import__('win32com.gen_py', globals(), locals(), ['2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52x0x2x8'], 0)
```

this file will not be automatically loaded.